# Angular2 do actions after dom has finished rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have a large ngx-bootstrap accordion on the page. When i open some of the lower accordions i want it to scroll the page so that the opened accorion starts at the top of the window. I achieved the  scrolling part with scrollIntoView, but now the issue is to execute it at the right time. im currently doing it in the ngAfterViewChecked, but the viewChecked is fired multiple times (mousemove, mouseenter, etc...). Is there a way to fire a piece of code only after the DOM has finished rendering separately from the angular2+ changeDetection?

SOLUTION

This is the solution that started working.

```
constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.elementRef = elementRef
  }

getData(){
   this.getService().then(result => {
      #do stuff with result
      setTimeout(() => this.scrollToBegin());
    }).catch((err: any) => {
    });
}

scrollToBegin(): any{
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
    }
```

Comment: what is wrong with `ngOnInit` hook. It is fired after the all the bindings are displayed. And more importantly it is fired once.

Comment: But i need it fired every time an accordion is opened. All the ngOnInits are done when i open the page. after that it is no longer called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you just have `ngAfterViewChecked` and `ngAfterViewInit` for detecting dom updates.

In my experience, sometimes you need to write the code for dom changes inside a `settimeout` to schedule a macrotask (asynchronous update) for that so that your code will run in the next cycle of change detection (which is exactly what you need). For more details see [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Place your could inside a `settimeout` in the end of your block code (and remove it from `ngAfterViewChecked`).
Some examples:

```
setTimeout(() => htmlInputElement.focus()); // focus an input
setTimeout(() => htmlElement.scrollIntoView()); // scroll into view
```

Comment: when i placed it inside the afterViewChecked it didnt work. But if i added it as the last thing AJAX does, it started to work.

Comment: @MarkoTaht you did right. I editted my answer to clear up this.

Answer (score 0):

Check Angular documentation for different lifecycle hook. Lifecycle hooks are called after the the component view is initialized.

`AfterViewInit()` will executes once as per your requirement.

> A callback method that is invoked immediately after Angular has
>   completed initialization of a component's view. It is invoked only
>   once when the view is instantiated.

`ngAfterVIewChecked()` is called after the component's view is loaded but it detects the changes and execute.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dumb response. but have you consider using the custom event `isOpenChange` shipped with accordeon:

```
      <accordion-group heading="Group with isOpenChange event listener" 
(isOpenChange)="log($event)">
        <p>Some content</p>
      </accordion-group>
```

and then in copponent:

```
log(event: boolean) {
    console.log(`Accordion has been ${event ? 'opened' : 'closed'}`);
  }
```

Comment: im already using it. isOpenChange invokes an ajax calls that get data from server. I tryed calling the scrollIntoView event at the end of ajax, but it does not work, since it is now doing the DOM updates.

Comment: OK. so it is a timing issue. you call the http endpoint and you want to perform some action when the call returns?

Comment: the data that comes from the endpoint creates a large table. so if the accordion is last in the list, you need to manually scroll to see the content, would be nice if it would automaticalli center on the list. vmoh_ir's answer was the solution i was looking for.

Comment: It's not a solution it is workaround. Calling set timeout is non deterministic way of achieving what you want. I would like to find a real solution. As I might encounter this problem in the future.

Comment: can you post the full solution. The code as it is written now.

Comment: I posted the important bits. Hard to post much more since a lot of abstractions and other client sensitive stuff.

Comment: I have a similar issue in Angular. I load a large table (thousands of rows).  I want to add a wait cursor and then put the cursor back to default when the table is rendered but there is no way to "know" (hook into) the render completion in order to place cursor back to default